# Destructuring the data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So the thing I am trying to do is to destructure coinsData, so I can use the id globally and keep the coinsData so I can iterate it somewhere else. Right now I am having a problem with typescript on export CoinProvider `Type '({ children }: { children?: ReactNode; }) => void' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'`Help would be appreciated

```
import React,{FC, useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export interface Coin  {
    id:string;
    name: string;
    current_price: number;
    symbol:string;
    price_change_percentage_24h:number
    image:string;
    market_cap:number
    market_cap_rank:number
    }
 export const CoinContext = React.createContext<Coin[] | undefined>(undefined)

 export const CoinProvider:FC= ({children}) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] =useState(false)
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(10);
    const [coinsData, setCoinsData] = useState<Coin[]>([])
  
    const handlePrevPage = () => {
      setPage((prevPage) => prevPage - 1);
    };
  
    const handleNextPage = () => {
      setPage((nextPage) => nextPage + 1);
    };
          
        useEffect(()=>{
         const fetchData= async()=>{
         setLoading(true);
         const response= await fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets? 
         vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&page=${page}&per_page=10&sparkline=false`)
         const result = await response.json()
            setCoinsData(result); 
            setTotalPages(totalPages);
            setLoading(false)
     
        }
            fetchData()
        },[page, totalPages])
  
      
    
      const Coins = coinsData.map((item) => {
        const {
        id, 
        } = item
    return(
    <CoinContext.Provider value={{Coins, totalPages, id, loading, handlePrevPage, handleNextPage, 
      currentPage:{ page }}}>
        {children}
    </CoinContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about `})` in line 47.
And logic there should look like this:

```
const Coins = coinsData.map((item) => item.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your component is missing a `return` statement.

Make sure to return an HTML that can be rendered.

```js
return <>
    {coinsData.map((item) => {
        const { id } = item
        return (
            <CoinContext.Provider value={[{ id: 'id', current_price: 1, image: 'image', market_cap: 0, market_cap_rank: 0, name: 'name', price_change_percentage_24h: 0, symbol: 'symbol' }]}>
                {children}
            </CoinContext.Provider>
        )
    })
    }
</>
```

And, don't forget to close the `map` function with the parenthesis `)`

#### In case, you only want to pass coinsData

```js
    return <CoinContext.Provider value={...coinsData}>
        {children}
    </CoinContext.Provider>
```

you can renounce the `map` and simplify your code with destructuring your `coinsData` directly.

Comment: it is showing the error in the value of the CoinContext.Provider ```Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Coin[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 mor```

Comment: you should pass a `list` not an `object`. Something like that: `value={[]}` and, of course, the list should contain elements of type `Coin`.

Comment: still can't pass the id nor the Coins

Comment: the problem is in  ```export const CoinContext = React.createContext()```

Comment: Updated the answer without using `map`. Should work.

Comment: There is something with ts syntax ```The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<ICoin | undefined>' ```

Comment: I dont get such an error. Can you share your current code?

Comment: return <CoinContext.Provider value={...coinsData}>
        {children}
    </CoinContext.Provider>